# How many ways can you get a sum $300$ from $100$ times choosing a number from $(0, 7, 11, 18)$

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can you get a sum $300$ from $100$ times choosing a number from $(0,7,11,18)$? Sets are ordered, for example, if sum is $18$, and you can choose 3 times, the answer is:
$(0, 0, 18), (0, 18, 0), (18, 0, 0), (7, 11, 0), (7, 0, 11), (0, 7, 11), (0, 11, 7), (11, 0, 7), (11, 7, 0)$. The number is very big (checked with python). What have I done so far: there are only $4$ ways to get $300$ with unordered sets from $(7, 11):$ $300 = 2 \cdot 7 + 26 \cdot 11 = 13 \cdot 7 + 19 \cdot 11 = 24 \cdot 7 + 12 \cdot 11 = 35 \cdot 7 + 5 \cdot 11$

Comment: Have you learned generating functions yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let's view the problem as finding the number of ways $100$ distinct boxes can have a sum of $300$ where each box can contain (1) nothing, (2) a $7$, (3) an $11$, or (4) both a $7$ and an $11$. Do you see how this is equivalent to the original problem?

Once you check that these are the same, note that if you want to make a sum of $300$ with $a$ $7$'s and $b$ $11$'s, then there are $\dbinom{100}{a}$ ways to put the $7$'s into boxes and $\dbinom{100}{b}$ ways to put the $11$'s into boxes. So there are $\dbinom{100}{a}\dbinom{100}{b}$ ways to put $a$ $7$'s and $b$ $11$'s into the $100$ boxes. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

@JimmyK4542 gave you a beneficial hint ,so i want you give you another approach that may facilitate your work.You said that i do not know generating fucntions ,but i believe that do not need to be master over generating functions to understand my suggested method.

We said that each places in the tuple can be seen like a distinguishable boxes and we want to put some numbers into these boxes such that each box can contain one number and the summation of the numbers in the boxes is equal to $300$.Whats more , it is given that there are $100$ "boxes".

Now , we know that each box can take either $0$ or $7$ or $11$ or $18$. Then ,lets show these numbers as exponential of a variable such as $\mathbf{\text{x}}$. Moreover , as you realize , we said that "each box can take either $0$ or $7$ or $11$ or $18$" ,so if you remember the basic counting rules , we use $\mathbf{\text{"+"}}$ when there is $\mathbf{\text{"or"}}$ connector.By using these informations ,  we can write the generating function form of a "box" by $$(x^0 +x^7 +x^{11} +x^{18})$$

As you mentioned in question ,we want to find all possible arragements such that $(18,0,7,...,11),(0,11,..,18,...,0)$ etc. Now , because of there are $100$ "boxes".I should work over $$(x^0 +x^7 +x^{11} +x^{18})^{100}$$ to find the coefficent of $x^{300}$ in the expansion of $(x^0 +x^7 +x^{11} +x^{18})^{100}$.Because ,as ou remember from binomial theorem , when we find the coefficient of an variable $x^n$  ,we choose one element form each paranteses to construct $x^n$. The coefficient of $x^n$ give use the number of all possible ways to construct $x^n$.

When we expand $(x^0 +x^7 +x^{11} +x^{18})^{100}$ , we select only one variable from each paranteses to contruct $x^{300}$. Do you get the idea ? It is so easy even for those who do not generating functions.

When we come to how to find the coefficients in these expansions. It can be found by hands , when you learn generating functions ,you will se some techniques , but i recommend you to use softwares to save time. When you click the *[link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+x%5E300+in+%28x%5E0+%2Bx%5E7+%2Bx%5E11+%2Bx%5E18+%29%5E100)* , you will see the calculation. As you see , the result is $$84,821,934,421,635,014,089,177,660,022,757,410,400$$